# selenium RC getAttribute not working in IE some times

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I tried selenium.

```
getAttribute("//ul[@id='zsTUL']/li[4]/div/@class")
```

This works fine in firefox,but in IE it is not working. When I check for `isElementPresent` it says `yes`,but `getAttribute fails`.

Answer (score 1):

Should it not be (note there's no "/" before "@class")?

`getAttribute("//ul[@id='zsTUL']/li[4]/div@class")`

Moreover, as per [this link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute), you should use "className" instead of "class" if you are using IE.